# aircrack-ng channel hopping issue

Tags: aircrack-ng

I cannot stop channel hopping on latest ubuntu, on  aircrack website it sais that newotk managers or similar programs cause this...when launching airmon-ng it warns me that processes like dhcpi, network-manager can cause problems.

I tried to kill these processes with `sudo kill -9 pid` but the processes are immediately restarted.

I am using the ath9k driver.

Comment: It does somewhat depend on the driver, but stopping all services noted in airmon-ng output should help.

Comment: Does this work if you roll back to an earlier kernel?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to stop their services, not simply kill the process. Here's what you can do:

```
sudo service avahi-daemon stop
```

- This stops the `avahi-daemon`.

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

- This stops Network Manager.

```
sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 terminate
```

- This should kill `wpa_supplicant` on your `wlan0` interface.

```
sudo kill -9 dhclient_pid
```

- Replace `dhclient_pid` with the `pid` of `dhclient`.

I suggest not executing all of these at once, but instead execute one and then check the channel hopping.

Answer (score 1):

Before setting your interface into monitor mode and trying to use any of the aircrack's wireless monitor and injection tools (ie: airodump-ng, aireplay-ng), always stop all network related services.

This is the command I use to stop all networking services and starting airmon:

```
sudo service avahi-daemon stop ; sudo service network-manager stop ; sudo wpa_cli -i wlan0 terminate ; sudo airmon-ng start wlan0
```

This is the command I use to stop airmon and starting all networking services back on:

```
sudo airmon-ng stop wlan0mon; sudo service network-manager start; sudo service avahi-daemon start
```

(Note that "wlan0mon" is the new notation for interfaces in monitor mode, starting with version 1.2-RC1. For previous versions, use "mon0")

Answer (score 0):

This should stop the network-manager, but I'm not sure if it will solve the issue:

```
sudo service network-manager stop
```

From:  http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1481660

Comment: Should I installl compat-wireless ?

Comment: Kling the process didn't help...what should i do ?

Comment: Sorry, I never found a good solution to the channel hopping problem.